# got popup warning while run project, Cannot run on the selected destination xcode 4.5.1

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [xCode Cannot Run on the Selected Destination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11767945/xcode-cannot-run-on-the-selected-destination)

I got  strange issue that while I am running my project I got a popup warning **Cannot run on the selected destination** like this below image:

[image]

I am trying to set my `Architectures` from Build Settings like:

[image]

But I can not fix it.

Please guide me how to solve this strange issue.

Comment: yes i just update my xcode version with ios6 and got this issue :(

Comment: Try to clean up your Xcode. Close it down completely, go to ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData and delete everything in the folder of DerivedData. Start up Xcode again, do a clean build. You may also want to reset your simulator if you are running on that. Then, run your project. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode 4.5 dropped support for armv6 binaries, it can only generate armv7 and armv7s binaries, so make sure that you are trying to run your App on an armv7 device (ie everything >= iPhone 3GS)

Comment: i run armv7 and got same issue thats why i am changing to armv6