# Xcode can not run the project on selected device

Tags: iphone, xcode, macos

I got the project from my team and i am working on it when ever i restart the system my Xcode not runs the project, but i am able to run other projects easily .... after i run the project with the changes i do it shows me

"Cannot run on the selected destination- The selected destination does not support the architecture for which the selected software is build. Switch to a destination that supports that architecture in order to run the selected software."
And if i run the original project it runs fine then i have to again copy and paste the codes that i did in the project after that it runs fine, but when i open my Mac the next day it does not runs and again i have to start from the original project, What is happening i don't know why after Restarting or Shut Down the project does not runs.

I am using Xcode 4.5.2 on iMac 21.5-inch - Software  OS X 10.8.2 (12C60)(Mountain Loin)

Processor 2.5 Ghz Intel Core i5, Memory 4 GB 1333 MHz DDR3.

Project target is iOS SDK 6.0 (on iOS 6 simulator).

Does Not runs on Simulator and on Device also.

Sometimes just runs on the simulator but not on Device.

I have tried :
Restarting the Mac.
Cleared Derived Data.
Reinstalling Xcode.

But still can't figure out .. Nothing helps .. plz Help me on this ...

Comment: What's your Device Version ? Please go through this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11767945/xcode-cannot-run-on-the-selected-destination

Comment: iPhone 4S ... but it's also not running on the simulator also

Comment: close Xcode and delete content of `Users/harmeet/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` and `~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator` then try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that if the project finds some cache memory problem then after restarting the system it some times start working fine or in case of same project with different destination with some minute changes you are running then it some times hanged in the device or simulator for that we have to need to switch off the device and restart again then after it start working fine. And if **the project code is in iOS 5.0 and the IPod/IPhone device os is 6.0 then it does not show in the device section for running. For that first you have to run the device to the xcode with ios 6.0 and then it start working fine . But here, you have to notice that for each and every time after switch off you have to run the device first with xcode 6.0.** But in your case some build target problem which is not clear to me . So , if you provide the details of bug then it will be easy for understand.

Comment: yes you are right .. but it says build successful and then it not runs on the device but it runs fine on the simulator ... But now it is not even running on the simulator .. and showing me "Cannot run on the selected destination" alert every time i try to run either on device or on simulator...

Answer (score 0):

Check under Build Settings > Architectures and set Architectures to Standard (armv7) or ${ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT} for all your profiles.

Set Base SDK to Latest iOS().

Set Build Active Architecture Only to NO for all profiles.

Set Valid Architectures to armv6 armv7 for all profiles. You may have to add either depending on what is already available.

Comment: checked all .. still no luck .. also my simulator hangs up now every time when i try to uninstall any of the already installed app's on simulator ....

Answer (score 0):

I have solve the problem using the below steps.

Close the Xcode

Delete the application from device

Restart the device

then re-run the application

it working fine..