# What does The destination does not support the architecture means?

Tags: xcode, facebook

I have the same problem with [Xcode Cannot Run on the Selected Destination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11767945/xcode-cannot-run-on-the-selected-destination)

> The destination does not support the architecture for which the
>   selected software is built. Switch to a destination that supports that
>   architecture in order to run the selected software.

I tried the solutions there and it doesn't work.

So I'll try to do something more reasonable.

What does the error means anyway? What is Xcode trying to say when it says to switch to a destination that supports that architecture? Where is the archtecture specified? What software? What is the problem?

While solutions may be nice what I am looking for is understanding of what it really means.

1. The project used to work
2. The project still work in real iPhone but not simulator
3. I used the newest facebook SDK. However, it run before even after the SDK. It's after I clean project it doesn't work.

Comment: I got this error today, tried a few things, googled it, ended up here, quit Xcode and re-opened it, and the error was gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I don't have a solution for your problem, I can answer your question, namely, what does Xcode **thinks** is wrong and what does the error means.

So, the destination is actually your simulator in this case (could be the iPhone as well, if you're building for it). The architecture is decently explained [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_CPU_architectures). What you need to understand is that in order for a software to run on a specific architecture it needs to be build for it(or assembled for it, to be more precise). That means that for the same software the CPU instructions are not the same for an iPhone (which has an ARM CPU) as they are for your iMac (which is x64).

Now, with the above in mind, what Xcode is trying to say is that you are trying to build the wrong architecture for your simulator and you should switch to a different destination that supports that architecture (as you mentioned, you can build just fine on the iPhone, which is a different architecture) in order for the software to run.

It could be an Xcode bug or a misconfiguration. **You're probably better off creating a new project and copy all your classes into it than hunting it down.**

Comment: Actually how to best do that?

Comment: Yes, that would do it too.

Answer (score 0):

You'll be happy to know this problem has a very simple solution. Select Info.plist in your project navigator tree and make sure it is not assigned to a target. I have confirmed this is the correct solution. If building for iOS 6 or earlier you may also need to add armv6 to supported architectures