# XCode 6. Architecture

Tags: xcode6

I have application and I test it all time for iPhone 4s.
Today I've tried to test with iPhone 5s. Simulator was starting long time but it did.
I changed it again to iPhone 4s and right now I can't start it:

> iPhone 4s cannot run project. project does not have an architecture
>   that iPhone 4s can execute.

I'm going to

> Build Settings

and change

> Architectures

to

> $(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT)

but it doesn't help. What XCode changed when I've tried start it with iPhone 5s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solve with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12708264/1146533) solution.

Before this I changed architectures to

> $(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT)